# Git SVN migration works but later fails with no changes

Tags: git, svn, migration

As everyone is moving to Git I gave my team the option to stay on SVN or migrate to Git. They voted to go with Git so I started down the long traumatic path of trying to migrate.

**Aim**

A one time migration from SVN to Git, including SVN history and the latest 10 SVN tags. In short we start the migration on Friday and on Monday when we start work we use Git from then on.

**Background**

We have a non-standard SVN structure that is as follows if you imagine a folder structure, for branches these are named after the version, the tags are named after the specific release of a branch, feature branches are named after task:

- Trunk
- Branches

  - 1
  - 2
  - ...
  - X
- Tags

  - 1

    - 1.0
    - 1.1
  - ...
  - X

    - X.0
- FeatureBranches

  - TaskID-AFewWorksSoYouDontHaveToLookUpTaskId

I'm attempting to migrate Trunk to "main", Tags will become tags in Git. We plan to follow the GitFlow branching scheme and thus will have a "development" Git branch too, with temporary release and feature branches as necessary.

**What I Did**

After many person hours of time spread out over months of time, with mammoth levels of frustration and hair pulling, I finally came up with the following batch file that does all the work and pushes it all to an empty AzureDevOps git repo

```
rem Check for Azure parameter
echo off
if [%1]==[] goto missingParam

rem Main migration
git svn init --prefix "" --no-metadata --trunk=Trunk --branches=Branches --tags=Tags https://OurSVNServerRepo/svn/MyProject/
git lfs install
copy /Y ..\authors-transform.txt
copy /Y ..\config .\.git
git svn fetch --log-window-size=1000 --ignore-paths="[Bb]in/|[Oo]bj/|ThirdPartyUtilities/|ReportServerConfig/Packages/|.bak$" -A authors-transform.txt
copy /Y ..\.gitattributes
copy /Y ..\.gitignore
git add .gitattributes
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Initial commit, git config files"

rem Tag creation
git for-each-ref --format='%%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/tags > gitTags.txt
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=/'" %%t in (gitTags.txt) do git tag "%%u/%%v" "%%t/%%u/%%v" && git branch -D -r "%%t/%%u/%%v"
del gitTags.txt

rem Clear out what remains of SVN
rd /S /Q .\.git\svn
copy /Y ..\configPostMigration .\.git\config

rem Tidy up incorrect tag creation
git tag -d 40/40.0@13074
git tag -d 40/40.0@13190
git tag -d 41/41.0@13753
git tag -d 41/41.1@13892
git tag -d 42/42.0@14355
git tag -d 42/42.0@14365
git tag -d 43/43.0@14607
git tag -d 44/44.0@15100
git tag -d 45/45.0@15633
git tag -d 46/46.0@16048
git tag -d 46/46.1@16118
git tag -d 46/46.1@16150
git tag -d 46/46.2@16380
git tag -d 47/47.0@16853
git tag -d 47/47.1@17024
git tag -d 48/48.0@17435
git tag -d 49/49.0@18075
git tag -d 50/50.0@18556
git tag -d 51/51.0@18940
git tag -d 51/51.1@19103
git tag -d 51/51.1@19136
git tag -d 52/52.0@19320

rem Tidy up after migration
rd /S /Q ThirdPartyUtilities

rem Set the remote and push to Azure.
git remote add origin %1
git config lfs.%1/info/lfs.locksverify true
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags

rem Create develop branch and push to Azure.
git checkout -b development
git push origin development
goto:eof

:missingParam
echo You must specify the Git URL, typically of the form "https://Name-Of-Organization@dev.azure.com/Name-Of-Organization/Name-Of-Project/_git/Name-Of-Project.git"
```

The config file copied in looks like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    noMetadata = 1
    url = https://OurSVNServerRepo/svn/MyProject/
    fetch = Trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    tags = Tags/46/*:refs/remotes/tags/46/*
    tags = Tags/47/*:refs/remotes/tags/47/*
    tags = Tags/48/*:refs/remotes/tags/48/*
    tags = Tags/49/*:refs/remotes/tags/49/*
    tags = Tags/50/*:refs/remotes/tags/50/*
    tags = Tags/51/*:refs/remotes/tags/51/*
    tags = Tags/52/*:refs/remotes/tags/52/*
    tags = Tags/53/*:refs/remotes/tags/53/*
    tags = Tags/54/*:refs/remotes/tags/54/*
    tags = Tags/55/*:refs/remotes/tags/55/*
```

After the SVN fetch command the post config file that is copied in is:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
```

**Outcome/Problem**

It takes many hours (15+) to process the SVN repo, it all seems to work fine I can see filenames whizzing past as it processes each revision from 1 to the latest. There are no error messages, but at the end there are no files in my local folder where this is running and all that gets pushed to Azure is the .gitattributes and .gitignore files.

The real kick in the balls annoying thing about this is I have tested this multiple times and it has worked multiple times in the past, i.e. my local folder and Azure is full of files from the SVN repo. The reason I've tested it so many times and not just switched is because there are several internal project related things that need to be rejigged because of the move to Git and those are getting done slowly over time. Periodically I run the script to ensure it's working fine. In fact after adding the final push to Azure bit I ran it about 3 or 4 times one after the other with a delete of the Azure side in between each one to double check it would be fine.

When Git is processing the deltas and all the stuff it does it has 200 or 300 odd MB of it and if you clone the Git repo from Azure to a new folder it likewise processes the same amount of stuff so it seems like there is a hell of a lot of metadata in Git about the files.

**Git Details**

I have tried running this on a Windows 10 Pro and Windows 11 Pro machine with Git versions:

- git version 2.30.0.windows.2
- git version 2.35.1.windows.2

**If any Git mega guru can shed any kind of light on why Git is behaving like this I would be much appreciated. This kind of will-it-won't-it-work-this-time behaviour is giving me major anxiety over switching to it.**

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be working fine (as it did already before). I verified this by performing your steps on a small test repository that has the same structure as yours.

If your current SVN "Trunk" *really* isn't empty (is it? : ), then I'd suggest to troubleshoot this by manually performing the steps in your script and -- after each step -- to verify that the current state is really what it is supposed to be. Also, carefully look for error messages and warnings.

Troubleshooting a process that runs for 15 hours is difficult. For debugging purposes, you can use the `-r` option of `git-svn` to limit the import process to a much shorter history.

In general, using `git-svn` for repository migration purposes appears like a natural solution, but it isn't (and this was never the original design goal). At your current stage this advice comes probably too late, but I'd rather recommend the [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/reposurgeon/) tool for migration tasks. The tool has a steep learning curve, but it is *blazingly* fast; it's highly reliable and it handles all kinds of uncommon SVN repository structures and histories.

Comment: I managed to find someone internally from another team who is taking a look. They think they may have found the problem, if so I'll report hack here. Took a look at the reposurgeon page and migrating SVN doesn't appear to be it's main purpose either. Like you say though too late now.

Comment: Citing the `reposurgeon` main page, it can "be used to script production of very high-quality conversions from Subversion to any supported DVCS.", and I second this. Anyways, good that you found support internally, let us know about the root cause once it has been found!

Comment: It seems the authors-transform.txt file was out of date in the gap between working and not working. So new author commits made it fail. The problem is the way it fails is very poor. Given there are no files after it completes, it would be much better if it just errored out and stop when it encountered the problem to make it easier to debug.